# .htaccess re-write urls and get variables

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using the following `.htaccess` code to force the `www` into my website domain name.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now I want to make my change my urls from this:

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?i=something
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/something
```

but I still want to have the ability to go to

`www.mysite.com/admin.php`(for example) as a separate page.

I tried adding this code `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?i=$1 [NC]` to my `.htaccess` file, but when I type anything after the `/` it will be considered as a get variable. How do I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this in one .htaccess file at root directory.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin\.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?  /index.php?i=$1    [L,NC]
```

If `admin.php` can be any file, just replace

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin\.php  [NC]
```

with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

To redirect to a 404 error handler script, add one line like this one:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path/404.php
```

This is just an example, modify accordingly.

Comment: Your code worked, but I have many other pages such as images.php, rss.php, articles.php, ect. Do I need to add this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !images\.php  [NC]`for each one of them ? Is there a general code for that ?

Comment: It worked, but now when I type a page that does not exist (with a .php or .html at the end) I get a empty page. Can I redirect to a 404 page ?

Comment: Okay. I will update my answer with a 404 redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?i=$1 [L]  // www.mysite.com/something/
```

**OR**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?i=$1 [L]  // www.mysite.com/something
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add expiation like this it must be before your RewriteRule `S=1` Skip RewriteRule that is after expiation see this page for more information about this flags http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/admin\.php$ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^ admin.php [S=1,L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?i=$1 [NC]
```